# Refreshing excel without opening actual file?

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel

I just created ms query in excel to retrieve data from sql server. I'm using another program that connect to excel  to create fancy graphs and etc. So excel is just  a processing file. It takes a while to  open and refresh  data in excel file. Is there a simple way to refresh data with out opening file. if not, is there a way to create script in C# or VB to accomplish this. I have visual studio installed on my computer and if takes the hard way I'm prepared to to it the hard way.

Excel allows me to save ms query as a separate file!

Comment: If you have control over the server, try WCF Data Services (OData). They appear to mesh better with what you're after based on what you've disclosed.

Comment: Why are you using Excel at all then? Just query the data in the sql server directly from your program that creates the graphs.